Yii search function update
I created a simple Database with a few rows :
.
I created this page using the Gii CRUD:

I would like that when I search on the Value column for example "10" it shows me all the rows with the value >= 10 but < 11, in my case it should shows me row n. 1,3,4.
I created this query that could be used but i don't know where i should use it:
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE 1 AND Value >= 10 AND Value < 10+1;

10 is related to my example, but it should be replaced with the value i'm searching for
I used phpmyadmin to run the query and this is what it should show me:


But instead in the Gii created page it shows me this:


If you run the crud generator for your table there is a search class under: app/models/TablenameSearch.
No idea what you did with "created a yii page"?
You added two phpmyadmin screen but didn´t mention what you actual want to change in yii?
Take a look at: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii

With "created a yii page" I wanted to say that i used the Gii CRUD... my bad :(
The phpmyadmin screens were putted in to show the results i wanted, I'll update the question to make it more understandable! Thank you for your answer

Did you check the search model class gii generated? There is a function search, which defines how yii uses the filter input. By default yii uses andFilterWhere function which checks if the value is equal. Thats why u only see the row with exactly 10. Change:
$query->andFilterWhere([['Value' => $this->Value]]);
To:
$query->andFilterWhere([['between', 'Value', $this->Value, $this->Value+1]]);
